# Отслеживание закрытие процесса и последующее выполнение команд (BAT/CMD)

Tags: windows-7, cmd, bat, windows-xp

Здравствуйте! Пишу батник который после закрытия игры будет сохранять копию файла сейва в другое место. Игра использует FlashPlayer и по этой причине сохраняет сейв в папку флеша %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects\XKYZFD9J\localhost\ и частенько затирается(размер хранилища стоить по максимуму и программы очистки туда не ходят). Застрял на этапе ***мониторинга батником процесса*** и после закрытия игры выполнить поиск файла с расширением .sol в подпапках и скопировать его. Файл буду использовать на Windows 7 и ХР. Кто сталкивался с такой задачей и сможет подсказать? Спасибо за ответ.
**Дополнение:**
Игра работает через стим и для запуска использую ссылку ( Steam URL ) вида steam://run/12345 и выбор пал на использование BAT для универсальности, и работы у разных пользователей как на Win7 так и WinXP без надобности установки дополнительного софта.

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить список процессов командой `tasklist`, указав ей фильтр - после чего подсчитать число строк в выводе с помощью цикла `for /f`. При запущенной и не запущенной программах число строк будет различаться.

Теперь можно сделать цикл ожидания при помощи `goto`, который бы проверял нахождение состояние программы. Между итерациями цикла проверки лучше поставить паузу при помощи команды `ping localhost` с ключом `-n`.

Достоинство такого метода - все что требуется для решения задачи можно узнать самостоятельно при помощи команды `help`. Но я бы рекомендовал все же сменить язык программирования, к примеру на Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте саму игру из того же бат-файла, тогда батник будет ждать ее завершения.
PS1: раз это steam надо пробовать запускать так:
"C:\Program Files\Steam\steam.exe" "steam://run/12345" (возможно вторые кавычки не нужны и нужно поправить путь)

Comment: Так и делаю. start "" /wait %Game%, но после закрытия игры копирование не идет.

Comment: Без start надо.
%Game%
echo game terminated

Comment: Игра запускается через steam и я использую ссылку на игру типа steam://run/12345 так как в обход steam игра не будет работать. без start данная ссылка работать не будет.

Comment: Вот прямо так и не будет? :-) Надо смотреть в реестре чем обрабатывается протокол steam:// и вызывать этот файл. Опять же без start.

Comment: Обращение напрямую к .ехе игры выведет белое окно и все, а на ссылку будет стандартное сообщение: 'steam:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Дополнил первое сообщение.

Comment: И еще раз скажу: надо смотреть в реестре чем обрабатываются URLы вида steam://

Comment: Владимир, они, сюрприз, Стимом обрабатываются...

Comment: И, конечно же, все наизусть помнять какие при этом у стима будут параметры командной строки...

Comment: Проблема не в параметрах. Дело в том, что Стим, приняв команду на запуск игры, сразу же выходит, если только он запускается не первый раз. Дождаться выхода из игры запуская ее через Стим невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ, несколько более хакерский, заключается в том, чтобы переименовать файл с игрой, а вместо него всунуть свой скрипт. Скрипт получит все те параметры, которые должна получить игра - и сможет ее запустить, передав ей `%*`.

Тут появляется другая проблема - у скрипта расширение не `.exe`. Поэтому надо найти какую-нибудь легкую обертку над пакетными файлами (когда-то я видел такую в составе Денвера, который сборка Апача).

И еще одна проблема - автообновления в Стиме. После каждого из них подмену файла придется производить заного.