# Отслеживание закрытие процесса и автоматический запуск .BAT

Tags: cmd, bat

Здравствуйте, помогите составить код .bat файла:
Запуск программы .exe происходит с помощью .bat файла
Нужно что бы после завершении этой программы в процессах, она запускалась заново, как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422405/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-bat-cmd

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
set executable=C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
set process=calculator.exe

:begin
tasklist |>nul findstr /b /l /i /c:%process% || start "" "%executable%"
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto :begin
```

Некоторые пояснения:

- Первым делом, мы получаем с помощью команды `tasklist` список всех процессов, которые выполняются на компьютере.
- Вывод данной команды перенаправляем команде `findstr`, которая осуществляет поиск заданного процесса по его имени. Обратите внимание, что имя процесса (`set process`) и имя исполняемого файла (`set executable`) могут не совпадать.
- Если наш процесс ещё не запущен (не найден в выводе команды `tasklist`), то происходит его запуск `|| start "" "%executable%"`.
- Далее идёт задержка (`timeout /t 3 /nobreak`) на 3 секунды (задаётся параметром /t) и весь цикл повторяется с начала.
- Прервать выполнение командного файла, в данном случаи, можно нажатием <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:loop
start "" /w exefilename /parameters
goto loop
```

Но рекомендую попробовать сделать иначе. Зарегистрировать приложение как сервис, и штатными методами настроить перезапуск созданной службы при её остановке. А в батнике просто стартовать эту службу.