# Как переоткрывать остановленный питон проект?

Tags: python, bat

Есть ПК на win 11 на котором запушено 2 разных питон проект. Как можно отслеживать запушены ли питон проекты?Есть вот такой [способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615558/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-bat), но не понятно как отследить именно один из процессов питона и открыть именно его?

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica есть 2 питон проекта запущенные на пк через CMD как можно перезапускать закрытый при закрытии любого?

Comment: теоретически помимо имени процесса можно получить еще и аргументы с которыми он был запущен, думаю в случае отстутсвия интерфейса (GUI) это может помочь, еще один из вариантов получить в нужном процессе его id и записать в файл к примеру, после чего искать записааный id в текущих процессах, а если есть возможность связать эти 2 процесса как клиент-сервер то тогда и id процесса будет не нужен